# Creating UI in DLL and use it in external apps

Tags: c#, visual-studio, win-universal-app

Sorry, I don't have much experience in programming and English and my question might be awkward. It relates to Windows 10 applications for classic desktop and touch screens.

I want to add a nice-looking touch-oriented Modern-style UI to my non-Visual Studio application. It is possible to call an external .NET assembly from my app and use its public constructors, methods, properties, and handle its events.

So I’ve created a new WPF User Control Library project in Visual Studio, replaced default User Control with a new Window, and built a dll file. Now I can use it in my app as described above. Everything seems to work fine.

Here are the questions:

1. Am I doing it right? Is building a dll from WPF project the only way
   to make a UI dll that can be used in external applications?
2. How can I make the UI looks and acts like Windows Universal Apps (at least I want it to respond screen rotation)? As I understand I
   cannot build a dll from Universal App projects and I have to create
   WPF window, make it full screen, and add appropriate UI elements.
3. Is it possible to use Windows 10 contracts and extensions in such UI
   dll?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share your code between different programs, you have to make it a shared library which is `dll` in windows. I don't know the other two questions.